# How do I lock a window from closing?

Tags: window, lock

I’m great with computers, but I can’t seem to find a way to keep a window from being closed. I want to be able to open chrome, and keep it open, so that when someone tries to close out of it, it won’t let them. Any help?

Comment: I can defeat anyone who tries to fool around with / control my computer

Comment: For what purpose? Are you trying to re-invent kiosk mode?

Comment: If someone has physical access to a machine, they can shut it.

Comment: I work at Ace Hardware, and the computer we use to clock in is insanely slow. The numbskulls that I work with keep closing the website after they clock in, though. I’m just trying to find a way to keep the window from closing so that we don’t always have to wait for it to open again.